# How do I create an IMServicePlugin on OS X? No documentation on file structure

Tags: objective-c, macos

Apple has provided good documentation on the protocols for IMServicePlugin.framework, but provides literally zero documentation on how this is compiled, in what format, what keys for the services plist are what, etc. Has anyone had experience with this? If so, are you aware of any documentation on the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a sample plugin that implements IRC, you can find it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/legacy/library/samplecode/IRCServicePlugIn/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011125-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). I know that it says that it's legacy, but that's the only sample code you'll find I'm afraid.

If you want to build one from scratch, it's actually quite "simple": In Xcode, create a new project and select Bundle, link against the `IMServicePlugIn.framework` and make sure that your `Principal Class` conforms to the `IMServicePlugIn`. Then, well, do whatever you need to do. When in doubt about anything, the [`documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/IMServicePluginFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009478) is pretty extensive (but it seems like you've already found out about that).